# get parent route params inside canActivate

Tags: angular, routes, parent, router, canactivate

I've routes like this:

```
[
  {
    path: ':orgName',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: HomeComponent
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
      },
      {
        path: 'details',
        component: DetailComponent
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

How do I access orgName inside canActivate of AuthGuard?

I tried

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    console.log(route.params["orgName"])
}
```

but it prints undefined

Comment: `console.log(route.parent)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To access parent's params, try this:-

```
route.parent.params["orgName"]
```